# Viewing test images in tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

There are 2 things i want to clarify

1. Why is it that when i open tensorboard for eval file after training using object detection api, i see 2 of the same test image side by side? Does it mean that each picture goes through detection twice? I have attached an example below.

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QVan.png)

2. I only can view 9 test images in tensorboard but I have 16 test images. Is there a way i can view all 16 test images?

Answer (score 1):

You see two images side by side. The right image is your labeled image as groundtruth. The left image is your prediction result. Why only 9 test images is visible I can't tell you for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).